# CSS grid's multi row item pushes single row

Tags: html, css

I had some issue with multi-row item inside CSS grid. I'm not sure if its by design or weird behavior.

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 65% 35%;
    grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
    grid-template-areas: "head side" "body side";
}
.item-head {
    grid-area: head;
}
.item-body {
    grid-area: body;
}
.item-side {
    grid-area: side;
}
```

Basically, **item-side** span across two rows at right side. While **head** piece is on left side first row, so the height of **head** should be it's minimum content, but it actually got pushed by content inside **side**.

Here is demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Nness/pen/MrYMzQ?editors=1100#)

Here is one of fix I did, that attempt to use auto for head. [auto](https://codepen.io/Nness/pen/QawXPM?editors=1100#).

But when grid row is auto, it has other trouble. [here](https://codepen.io/Nness/pen/OzPeeb?editors=1100#0) is example demonstrate on situation where **body** doesn't have enough content.

The final version I came up with was [this](https://codepen.io/Nness/pen/xpbvwN?editors=1100#0). Which not use 2x2 grid, but just two columns.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows), we can see that `min-content` Is a keyword representing the largest minimal content contribution of the grid items occupying the grid track.

It make sense, but how come it got pushed away by multi-row content? If an item is span 2 rows, then it should only push that two rows height, not first row's height. I'm a bit confused on this, if someone could explain what is going on that will be great.

**Edit**:
If we use 1fr for `body` piece, then the content display correctly. Now that fr unit, also known as fraction of leftover space is noted as supported by IE Edge only from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex_value). While some other source from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/) comment, people saying it works in conjunction with grid layout.

I have tested fr unit on latest firefox and chrome, it works fine.

But the question still remains, the `side` area covers 2 rows, its context is 2 row, while head and body's context are 1 row. The line between those 1 row content got adjusted by content from 2 row area. No matter what calculation for `auto`, it should ignore anything that's not related.

[image]

The key to this issue is, cell across two rows should only affect total height of two rows, but never cause any change to individual rows. I have never encountered same issue on  WPF grid system, but in CSS grid, this is one of weird behaviour I have seen.

Comment: I don't undertand the question. Could you provide a sketch or something to illustrate?

Comment: If you look at the demo I have created in [here](https://codepen.io/Nness/pen/MrYMzQ), the cell that with green background's height is not decide by the content of green cell, but content of blue cell.

Blue cell is an area across two rows, the content inside shouldn't affect those single row cell. You need to view that demo inside desktop.

Comment: [sample screenshot](https://ibb.co/gBi2vo)

Answer (score 0):

Thats odd: When I (using Opera 54.0) unset overflow for item-side, the result differs. But still can't figure out what is defining the height then...

Anyway: I read somewhere, that min-content and max-content are not applicable to columns - only rows. This could explain the strange behaviour.

This source was mentioned there:
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#sizing-values